# Call SSRS Report in Windows Aplication

Tags: reporting-services

I have a windows application in asp.net c#,and i want to call a SSRS report on a button click event.How to call a SSRS report on Windows application.I have done the same in web application, what change i want to make in programmatic level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you do it on the windows application? There are 3 ways you can interact with SSRS from an application, report Server Web Service (SOAP), URL access and the reportViewer Controls for Visual Studio 2005.

Easiest way I would say are the controls. In this case, you can configure them in local mode or remote mode. In local mode you dont depend on the SSRS server and need to deploy the report file with your application (the file needs to be .rdlc, not .rdl). In remote mode you access SSRS directly and render the reports from it. There are other differences, like on local processing, reports can only be displayed using PDF, excel and image for example